# __await__ Exception in python

Tags: python, async-await

In a class A, if I define the **await** method and make await A() possible, how can I catch the exeptions raised under the **await** method ?

```py
class A:
    def __await__(self):
        raise ValueError("!!!!!") # want this thing to be seen.
        return self.happy().__await__()

    async def happy(self):
        return 1
```

Comment: why do you want to raise a value error in __await__ that goes against what __await__ is designed to do, await should return an iterator, and it does not take in any input except the class instance. I really don't understand the rationale behind raising ValueError in __await__

Comment: I need to break the flow once it is having some error